# I need to apply SearchView in a RecyclerView in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I was searching for how to implement a searchView in a RecyclerView. I found a couple of answers with all the data binding and all. Can't we do it in more simple way ? I am extracting my data from a SQLite database.

My Adatper will be Adapter(Context context, List list)
and I am getting the whole list of my data Item in main activity from the SQLite database and then calling the adapter with that list.

A short a simple method would be nice.

**EDIT:**

I tried this approach:

In my adapter class:

```
public void filter(String text) {
    Log.d("filter", items.toString());
    Log.d("filter", itemsCopy.toString());
    items.clear();
    Log.d("filter", itemsCopy.toString());
    if(text.isEmpty()) {
        items.addAll(itemsCopy);
    } else {
        text = text.toLowerCase();
        for (Item item: itemsCopy) {
            if(item.getTitleAdapter().toLowerCase().contains(text) ||
                    item.getContentAdapter().toLowerCase().contains(text)){
                items.add(item);
            }
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

In MainActivity:

```
final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.actionSearch);
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            adapter.filter(query);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            adapter.filter(newText);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Now This is my Log:

```
    03-26 01:41:39.293 27775-27775/com.codedweeb.notesandmemo D/filter: [com.codedweeb.notesandmemo.Item.Item@d2597af, com.codedweeb.notesandmemo.Item.Item@d9317bc, com.codedweeb.notesandmemo.Item.Item@449345, com.codedweeb.notesandmemo.Item.Item@e6fea9a, com.codedweeb.notesandmemo.Item.Item@c3dffcb, com.codedweeb.notesandmemo.Item.Item@c57f3a8]
03-26 01:41:39.293 27775-27775/com.codedweeb.notesandmemo D/filter: [com.codedweeb.notesandmemo.Item.Item@d2597af, com.codedweeb.notesandmemo.Item.Item@d9317bc, com.codedweeb.notesandmemo.Item.Item@449345, com.codedweeb.notesandmemo.Item.Item@e6fea9a, com.codedweeb.notesandmemo.Item.Item@c3dffcb, com.codedweeb.notesandmemo.Item.Item@c57f3a8]
03-26 01:41:39.293 27775-27775/com.codedweeb.notesandmemo D/filter: []
```

I don't understand, I called items.clear() then why the copy of items, which is itemsCopy is getting cleared too ?

Here is all the Initialization:

```
public Adapter(Context context, List<Item> items) {
    this.items = items;
    this.itemsCopy = items;
    this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.context = context;
}
```

Comment: Did you try implementing a filter in your adapter class?

Comment: yes I tried a filter, Wait I am gonna edit the question and add what I have done.

Comment: Can you show how you are initializing itemsCopy?

Comment: You should use itemsCopy = new ArrayList(items); 
and not itemsCopy = items;

Comment: I have added this in the question. I am doing it in the constructor.

Comment: then how should I copy all the elements from the list items to the new list itemsCopy ?

Comment: itemsCopy = new ArrayList(items);
This will do that. Try it out.

Comment: Thanks man, It did work and Now everything is working perfectly.

Comment: So the issue was you were holding the refernce of your itemList in your itemsCopy, hence clearing itemsCopy was actually clearing your itemList as well.

Comment: got it now :)
conflicts between pass by value and pass by reference. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to replace `this.itemsCopy = items`, with

```
this.itemsCopy = new ArrayList(items);
```

Comment: and then copy all the element of my list "items" before clearing it in the filter method. Thanks :)